# Set Bitmap to ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a Bitmap decoded from XML-File in this line:

```
decodeBase64(parser.getValue(e,KEY_PROJECTIMAGE));
```

I have also a ImageView in my Layout. I want to put the Bitmap in my ImageView.

I can't call: `projectView.setImageBitmap` but why?

Here is my decodeBase64 method:

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
     byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

and the getValue method:

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why can't you call the setImageBitmap method?

Comment: I don't know. the id the ImageView is projectView. If i try to call projectView in my onCreate method nothing happens. @Blackbelt yes it is

Comment: How are you declaring you projectView as ImageView??Code??

Comment: Is projectView the id? Try this: ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.projectView)).setImageBitmap(.......);

Comment: okay i got it... i forgot to declare the imageview... thank you!!

Comment: I get a NullPointerException at: ImageView projectv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.projectView); Is it because I have the ImageView in another Layout as the layout set in the setContentView?

Comment: yes...This imageview layout should be in the layout which you are setting in your setContentView.

Comment: can i declare the imageView from other layout?

Comment: No you can't. ImageView needs to be of your current layout.

Answer (score 2):

try with this..

ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepicUpload);

pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);